# Checking container size in same "if" statement as reading from it

Tags: c++, if-statement

Let's say I have a vector of unknown length.
I want to check if there is a value at vector[3] that is equal to x.

I have to first check if the vector has a length of at least 4.

```
if(vector.length()>=4)
{
   if(vector.at(3) == x)
     // Do something
}
```

My question is: Is it correct to write the same code like this:

```
 if(vector.length()>=4 && vector.at(3) == x)
   // Do something
```

?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Those are exactly equivalent tests (be careful about bracing of following statement block of course)

Comment: This is not `C` code.

Comment: interesting tangent - for similar code with `std::vector`, the main compilers are smart enough to optimize out the `.at()` behaviour

Comment: Note that `at()` performs bounds checking, which your `length()` check is already performing, so you can use `operator[]` instead to avoid the unnecessary overhead: `if (vector.length() >= 4 && vector[3] == x)`

Comment: One thing to note is that most stl containers use `size()` instead of `length()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these are equivalent.

The logical AND operator `&&` has what is referred to as *short circuit behavior*.  If the left operand evaluates to false (i.e. 0) then the entire expression is false and the right operand is not evaluated.

Comment: Important note: This applies to the **built-in operator `&&`** and not to any user-defined `operator &&()` overloads.